# Novel about a transmigrater with a sick mother and a brother that hates him

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this a long time ago.  The main character basically reincarnated into another world. He was the second oldest child of a poor farming family, and there was magic in the world. He was good at using magic from a young age and it created friction with his eldest brother who hated him for taking the limelight. I don't remember much after that but I know his mother got sick and he was able to help her. I also know that the main character eventually went to some academy and helped the lord of the village. Not sure about the details much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art or the names of any characters or places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the brother was stealing food from him as a baby the book is [Supreme Magus](https://www.webnovel.com/book/supreme-magus_12820870105509205). Webnovel gives the following synopsis:

> Derek McCoy was a man who spent his entire life facing adversity and
> injustice. After being forced to settle with surviving rather than
> living, he had finally found his place in the world, until everything
> was taken from him one last time. After losing his life to avenge his
> murdered brother, he reincarnates until he finds a world worth living
> in, a world filled with magic and monsters. Follow him along his
> journey, from grieving brother to alien soldier. From infant to
> Supreme Magus.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to specify the ways in which this matches the novel described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't. Specifying the author and the year in which it was published would be helpful too.

Comment: I love you so much omgggg , thank you so much.
it has sentimental meaning as I read that when I was at a terrible point in life, thank you again kind soul.

Comment: You are so welcome.